# How to echo string of another string shell variable

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, environment-variables

We would like to echo the value of a shell variable which has another variable string in its variable name.
eg:

we want the following output

```
var1=1
var2=2
```

We tried several various forms similar to the one below but they don't work

```
for j in {1..2}
do
   export var${j}=$j
   echo "var${j}=${var${j}}"
done
```

How do we set and echo shell variables containing variable string in their name?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In bash (or ksh), you can use the indirection syntax `${!var}` to reference the variable whose name is the value of `$var`. It has to be the complete name, so you have to do it like this:

```
for j in {1..2}; do
   # This could have been declare instead of export if you don't need
   # to export the variable.
   export var${j}=$j
   varname=var$j
   echo "var${j}=${!varname}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this as @rici explained but it is rarely a good idea. You could achieve the same thing with a simpler syntax if you use arrays instead:

```
var=("1" "2");
for j in {0..1}
do
    echo "var$j : ${var[$j]}"
done
```